# Measurability of a 'cone'

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let A be a (Lebesgue) measurable set in $ \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the 'cone with base A' $A(1) = \{\alpha x \in  \mathbb{R}^n : x \in A, \alpha \in (0,1] \}$.
Is B Lebesgue measurable? I assume it is, but lacking an argument. 
This should be true if $A$ is Borel set, because if $A$ is the union/intersection of some $A_i$'s, then $A(1)$ is the union/intersection of the $A_i(1)$'s. But what about those $A$'s, which are not Borel?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that the cone is always measurable. Consider a unit circle in $R^2$ and let $A$ be a subset of the unit circle that is not measurable in the natural 1-D measure of the circle. For example, let $A$ consist of representatives from each equivalence class of the points of the unit circle over rotations by rational angles.

The above set $A$, although not measurable in the unit circle's measure, is certainly measurable in the 2-D measure of $R^2$ and has measure 0. On the other hand, the cone over $A$ is not measurable in $R^2$.

Here's how you prove it: the unit disk less its centre consists of a countable number of copies of $A$: it's the union of copies of $A$ over all rotations by rational angles. If $A(1)$ was measurable with measure $a\ne 0$ then the area of the unit disk would be infinite by addition of measures. On the other hand, if $a=0$ then the area of the unit disk would be 0. Therefore $A(1)$ is not measurable.

Comment: I had no knowledge of such a set. Thank you very much!